# wp7 preload silverlight page

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have settings page in my wp7 application. I loads for quite long time first time since I add looping selector. I there any correct way to precreate\preload this page earlier;

Comment: Suggest you add some code and/or a more detailed explanation, otherwise this question will get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to preload the page but there are lots of other things that could be done to improve the load time/performance:

- Adjusting when in the page lifecycle the contents are loaded
- What's loaded
- The order items are loaded
- The complexity of what and how things are displayed
- Preload the data/model
- and many more...